# Генерация url при поиске

Tags: url, поиск, php

Таблица БД t_catalog:

```
    id  model_id    model_year
    80      394       2013

    php

    function catalogQuickSearch(){

            $tpl = $this->templates->tplRead("catalogQuickSearch.html");

            $arr = array(
                'catalogQuickSearch_title' => CATALOG_QUICK_SEARCH_TITLE,
                'catalogQuickSearch_help' => CATALOG_QUICK_SEARCH_HELP,
                'catalogQuickSearch_example' => CATALOG_QUICK_SEARCH_EXAMPLE,
                'catalogQuickSearch_primer' => CATALOG_QUICK_SEARCH_PRIMER,
                '_example_car' => $this->spec->modelName(3),
            );
            $tpl = $this->templates->tplReplace($tpl, $arr);

            $content = $tpl;

            return $content;
        }

    ХТМЛ

     <h4>{catalogQuickSearch_title}</h4>

        <form id="search" action="index.php">

            <input type="hidden" name="mod" value="models" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="details" />

            <div class="catalogQSQuery"><input type="text" name="q" id="q" onblur="if($(this).val() == '')$(this).val('{catalogQuickSearch_help}');" onclick="if($(this).val() == '{catalogQuickSearch_help}')$(this).val('');" value="{catalogQuickSearch_help}" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="suggestion('catalogUI', $(this));" /></div>
            <div class="catalogQSSubmit"><input type="image" src="templates/images-v2/searchBtn.gif" /><br /></div>
            <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
        </form>

        <div class="catalogQSExample">{catalogQuickSearch_example}: {catalogQuickSearch_primer} <a onclick="$('#q').val($(this).text()); $('#search').submit(); return false;" href="#">{_example_car}</a></div>
```

Поиск генерирует другой: http://www.site/index.php?mod=models&cmd=details&q=2014+Jeep+Grand+Cherokee+%2714&x=28&y=14

**Вопрос**: Как переписать(дописать) код, чтобы поиск генерировал URL такого плана: http://www.site/models/jeep/grand-cherokee-14/2014 ?

**Уточняю** Есть функция вывода популярных авто. Но она выводит списком (таблицей) популярные автомобили - 15 шт. А мне нужно чтобы среди этих популярных авто находило 1 авто заданное в поиске...

```
Как это сделать, кто знает прошу помочь?

    function catalogPopular(){

            $sql = "SELECT 
                        ".$this->catalogTable.".*,
                        ".$this->defaultTable.".parent_id AS maker_id
                    FROM 
                        ".$this->defaultTable.", ".$this->catalogTable."
                    WHERE 
                        ".$this->defaultTable.".id = ".$this->catalogTable.".model_id
                        AND ".$this->catalogTable.".status = '1'
                        AND ".$this->catalogTable.".pinned = '1'
                    ORDER BY 
                        date_post 
                    DESC LIMIT 15
                    ";

            $DBres = $this->dataBase->execQuery($sql);
            if(!$this->dataBase->getRowNums($DBres))
                return '';

            $tpl = $this->templates->tplRead("catalogPopular.html");

            $arr = array(
                'catalogPopular_title' => CATALOG_POPULAR_TITLE,
            );
            $tpl = $this->templates->tplReplace($tpl, $arr);

            $tempTd1 = $this->templates->tplGetLoop($tpl, 'td1');
            if($DBres)
            foreach($this->dataBase->loadObjects($DBres) as $val){

                $arr = array(
                    '_car_title' => $this->spec->modelName($val->id),
                    '_car_url' => $this->spec->modelURL($val->id),
                );
                $allTd1 .= $this->templates->tplReplace($tempTd1, $arr);
            }

            $content .= $tpl = $this->templates->tplPutLoop($tpl, 'td1', $allTd1);

            return $content;
        }

    }
```

Comment: урл такого плана site/models/jeep/grand-cherokee-14/2014 нужно еще и обработать, а это вопрос куда более сложный

Comment: Давайте совместно поработаем...

Comment: Либо редирект через js, либо редирект на скрипте-приемщике формы. Сама форма никогда такого генерировать не будет.

Comment: Fike

Прошу помочь исходя из моего уточнения в вопросе...